# What screws do I need for my PSU?

Tags: power-supply, case

This Christmas I bought new PC. When I started to assemble it, I found that my case (Artic Cooling Silentium T11) has 12 screws for HDD, DVD etc, and 6 screws for the expansion cards.

Well, first thing that surprised me was, why only 6 screws for expansion card, when case has actually 7 slots. And second, what are PSU screws supposed to some with? The PSU, Case or nothing? Because neither PSU or Case had them. PSU is Evolve Storm 600W.

Well, I know case and PSU are not some high end devices, but still, would it hurt them to add 1 screw for expansion cards and 4 for PSU?

Is this situation normal, or which one (Case or PSU) does normally screws come with?

Comment: Most electronics places sell small bags of miscellaneous computer harware screws for cheap. Case manufacturers have no guidelines on what screws are included, its whatever they feel like including at the time of manufacture, some include more, some less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you purchase the parts.

When I build, I usually buy OEM parts and I have mixed results. The amount of screws really changes with every manufacturer, but typically, they only come with the case.

I usually get enough to put the motherboard to the case and enough for 2 hard drives / 1 optical drive.

When the case does not already include a PSU, there usually is another 4 screws included, but again, this varies between manufacturer.

When you purchase retail parts, usually you get a lot more of everything, e.g. Hard drive, optical drive, power unit - all comes with their own set of screws.

Comment: Well I have retail ones...

Comment: Then your case should of come with 4 extra, or the case manufacturer assumed you wouldn't need them (possibly assume smaller motherboard that uses less or similar.)

Comment: Well actually none of screws which came with Case are suitable for PSU. there only 2 types. Luckilly I have some spare from PC I built some years ago. But still, its not fair.

Comment: @user32569 Well the screws have technical names.  e.g. 6-32(hdd) 4-40(optical), but then there's a UK US thing.. M3 screw or M1 screw  I can't quite remember.. Does your power unit have different screws to your hdd and optical drives? I think I normally use HDD screws..

Comment: ah M1 is perhaps nothing more than a motorway in england. Here is a page about computer screws  6-32 4-40 and M3  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_case_screws